# Insert parent id for csv data

Tags: python

I have a csv file in this format

```
Country State   City    County
X       A       
X       A       R   
X       A       R       X
X       A       R       Y
X       B       
X       B       S   
X       B       S       X
```

It represent a tree (containment) relationship.
Now I need to insert id and parent id, which reflect this relationship.
For example:
Parent of Y (id=5) is R, which has an id 3. Hence parent field of Y is 3.

```
id  parent  Country State   City    County
1   0       X    
2   1       X       A       
3   2       X       A       R   
4   3       X       A       R       X
5   3       X       A       R       Y
6   1       X       B       
7   6       X       B       S   
8   7       X       B       S       X
```

As there are thousands of entries, it is tedious to do manually.
How can I do this in Python. That is to read the file (first block) and output with the id and parent inserted (second code block above)

Comment: you should looks at teh csv module http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: @rodion I edited the post. Let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Do you have to do it programatically? Could you just use a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: This solution should be clearer. It's a rework of the previous solutions ([1](http://codepad.org/YVXoXFpn), [2](http://codepad.org/kGANnQ2q)) rather than a new approach. A single loop and no copying makes this one easier to understand.

import copy
    import csv
    import StringIO

```
csv_str = """X,,,
X,A,,
X,A,R,
X,A,R,X
X,A,R,Y
X,B,,
X,B,S,
X,B,S,X
"""

reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(csv_str))

idx = 0
data = []

for row in reader:
    # insert the row id
    row.insert(0, idx + 1)

    # insert a dummy parent id, it will be replaced with the real
    # value later
    row.insert(1, -1)

    # how deep is the current row
    depth = len([r for r in row if r is not ''])
    # insert the depth as the last value in the row
    row.append(depth)

    if idx > 0:
        # if it's not the first row, calculate it's parent

        # calculate the depth of the previous row
        prev_depth = data[idx - 1][-1]
        if depth > prev_depth:
            # if it's deeper than the previous row, then the previous
            # row is the parent row
            row[1] = data[idx - 1][0]
        elif depth == prev_depth:
            # if it's the same depth as the previous row then it has
            # the same parent as the previous row
            row[1] = data[idx - 1][3]
        else:
            # if it's shallower than the previos row, find the
            # nearest previous row with the same depth and use it's
            # parent as this row's parent.
            ridx = idx - 1
            while (prev_depth != depth and ridx >= 0):
                prev_depth = data[ridx - 1][-1]
                ridx -= 1
            row[1] = data[ridx - 1][0]
    else:
        # if it's the first row it's parent is 0
        row[1] = 0

    # store the new row
    data.append(row)
    idx += 1


# write the CSV
output = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in data:
    # skip the depth value in each row
    writer.writerow(row[:-1])

print output.getvalue()
```

You can see the code at work here: http://codepad.org/DvGtOw8G

Comment: John, thank you verymuch. I found a SO post for similar structure here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711794/generic-way-to-create-nested-dictionary-from-flat-list-in-python , but that goes above my head. I will try your solution and also try to understand other one.

Comment: Also, thank you for the effort and time on it.

Comment: I've rejigged this solution to avoid unnecessary loops and copying. I added some comments too so it should be easier to understand now.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't attractive (and not Python, so apologies if doing it this way isn't an option), but if you want to avoid scripting, you could use this (assuming the setup in the screenshot):

```
=INDEX(
       $A$1:$A$9,
      MATCH(
            INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COUNTA(C2:F2)+1)),
            INDIRECT(
                  SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COUNTA(C2:F2)+1,4) & ":" & ADDRESS(1,COUNTA(C2:F2)+1,4),"1","")),
             0),
        1)
```

This assumes that the order of the data is such that a parent's id is defined before it is ever referenced. To populate `ID`, you can use `Fill Series` to create an incrementing list. Again, this isn't pretty (and may not be appropriate for what you need), but it is one way you could avoid scripting (if you need Python, JoranBeasley's suggestion of using the CSV module is the way to go).

[image]