# Generic way to create nested dictionary from flat dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking for a generic way to convert a flat dict like this:

```
{
    "det_0_prod_di_0_field" : "value", 
    "det_0_prod_di_0_adi_0_field" : "value", 
    "det_0_prod_di_0_adi_1_field" : "value", 
    "det_1_prod_di_0_field" : "value", 
    "det_1_prod_di_0_adi_0_field" : "value", 
    "det_1_prod_di_0_adi_1_field" : "value", 
}
```

Into this:

```
[
    {
        "det" : {
            "prod" : [{
                "di" : {
                    "field" : "value", 
                    "adi" : [{"field" : "value"}, {"field" : "value"}]
                }, 
            }]
        }, 
        "det" : {
            "prod" : [{
                "di" : {
                    "field" : "value", 
                    "adi" : [{"field" : "value"}, {"field" : "value"}]
                }, 
            }]
        }
    }
]
```

Notice that I have to create lists of dict for items that "repeat"... Also, It needs to be generic, because it can have many "levels of nesting"... every time "_0", "_1" etc appears in a key, a list should be created...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic way to create nested dictionary from flat list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711794/generic-way-to-create-nested-dictionary-from-flat-list-in-python)

Comment: Split your dict into a list of dicts and follow method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711794/generic-way-to-create-nested-dictionary-from-flat-list-in-python

Comment: What have you tried? What's your rule for what counts as an index vs. a key? What's your rule for what happens if indices are skipped or appear out of order? What's your rule for what happens if you get both an index and a key under the same prefix?

Comment: This isn't a dup of the first question, because (a) he's using a compound key string rather than a hardcoded set of "key columns", and (b) he specifies sub-lists by using index values.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, it is a very different question. I read the other question before creating this one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first step is obviously to split each key into components:

```
target = {}
for key, value in source.items():
    components = key.split('_')
```

Now, what do you do with those components? Walk each one from left to right, keeping track of the current collection and the index or key to the next one, creating any missing sub-collections along the way.

You haven't specified your rule for what counts as an index vs. a key, what happens if indices are skipped or appear out of order, what happens if you get both an index and a key under the same prefix, etc., so I'll just pick some arbitrary rules for each—just treat every component as a key, because that makes for the shortest code. That's obviously not the rule you want, but if you understand the code, you should be able to adapt it as appropriate; if not, you need to understand it before you try to use it.

```
    subtarget = target
    for component in components[:-1]:
        subtarget = subtarget.setdefault(component, dict())
    subtarget[components[-1]] = value
```

If you understand the code but don't know how to adapt it, you probably have to look up the `int` function, the `try` statement, or the `list.insert` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The starting dict basically represents a flat tree. "det" is the parent of "prod", "prod" is the parent of "di", "di" is the parent of "adi". Everything that has an index can have multiple occurences. I can have many "det", but ONLY ONE "prod" inside a given det. Also, anything can have many fields like det_0_prod_field1:value, det_0_prod_field2:value... The structure is perfectly defined... I could not come up with an algorithm that will transform the flat dict into a nested one... I will continue in the comment below...

Comment: There is one other rule: if I have 2 consecutives non multiples like this: det_0_prod_item_field1:value, det_0_prod_item_field2:value, I do not want "item" to go "under" "prod", despite the fact that prod is parent of item... I want the key in the resulting dict to remain flat, like {prod_item_field1:value, prod_item_field2:value, prod_di:[{...}]}... Also, I have no idea how to adapt the code you created to achieve that... Thank you very much for the help...

Answer (score 1):

You might consider following and using then formencode's approach of serializing structures to flat names and then reading them back in.

http://www.formencode.org/en/latest/modules/variabledecode.html#module-formencode.variabledecode